# How do I pass xaml control parameter like object, routedEventArgs to the Command?

Tags: c#, xaml, events, mvvm, icommand

I am trying to figure out how to use a control parameters that you have int typical event-handler like click using commands. I learnt how to run a method using commands but what if

1. I want to refer to my buttons in UI when my Methods are in a totally different class?
2. How do I get to the parameters of the pressed control?

Here is what I have got, not sure if its professional way of using it, hope yes:)
That's the class and command bound to the control:

```
class Commands
{
    private ICommand rectangleCommand;

    public ICommand RectangleCommand
    {
        get { return rectangleCommand; } 
    }

    public Commands()
    {
        rectangleCommand = new RelayCommand(makeItInvisible);
    }

    private void makeItInvisible()
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Works");
        dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

That's my `RelayCommand` class that implements `ICommand` and uses `Action` delegate to point to the method in `Commands` Class:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private Action action;

    public RelayCommand(Action action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

That works fine, but I need more than that. :)
Here is my XAML -code. I just created it to exercise INottifyProperyChanged and ICommand interface. Lets assume that: First I want to pass to another  page object I created and use it in OnNavigatedTo method. Another scenario would be that I want to make make change some of the properties of the button that has been pressed. Using standard event handlers in the code behind I do that very easily using object sender, routedEventArgs e that has been passed. How do I do that using commands?

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Person}" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="808,84,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="85" Width="323" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,107,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="435"/>
    <Button Content="Button" x:Name="Button1" Margin="100,375,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75" Width="257" Background="#FF39349E"/>
    <Button Content="Button" x:Name="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="457,375,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75" Width="257" Background="#FF39349E"/>
    <Button Content="Button" x:Name="Button3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="830,375,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="75" Width="257" Background="#FF39349E"/>
    <Button Content="Show The Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="833,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273" Height="69" Background="#FFE07031"
            DataContext="{StaticResource Commands}" Command="{Binding RectangleCommand}"/>


</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you please post the XAML-code and provide the concrete goals to be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You use the `CommandParameter` `Dependency Property` in order to pass a parameter in.

```
<Button Content="Show The Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="833,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273" Height="69" Background="#FFE07031"
        DataContext="{StaticResource Commands}" CommandParameter"Show the message" Command="{Binding RectangleCommand}"/>
```

But what you are trying to achieve is probably better achieved via triggers. Your command should not know anything about the Button, or the UI ideally.